# Javascript Regex find instance of one string and replace the string that comes after it

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm working on a project for work that will allow users to change values in an API function call easily.

The values of the api look like this: FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=Doe&CUSTOMER_ID=284139&WHATEVER=XXXX

There can be any number of fields with a value.  Each field will have a different name.

Say I want to change the last name to Johnson.  I could also want to change the ID to something.  Users have the option to choose which field they would like to change the value of.  This makes me think I need a new RegExp object.

I have the field name and the new value in variables like so

```
var field = LAST_NAME (gotten from getElementById.value of a select option)
var value = Johnson (pulled from the value the user choose)
```

I am looking for a regular expression that will be able to go in and find the field name and then replace the value.

I have worked with perl and was thinking something like this

```
newApiCall = ApiCal.replace(new RegExp(/(.*)(&field=)(.*)&/), $3, value);
```

This would put everything before field in $1, &field= into $2, and then $3 would be the value I'm replacing.  Hopefully then $3 gets replaced with the new value.

Any ideas how to do this in javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just split the string by `&`, then split each string by `=`, and you will get key-value pairs... Now replacement is just finding the key/value you need replacing

Comment: @nem this is not a bad idea and would allow for greater scale-ability if I wanted to ever add more values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dynamic regex generated using a variable:

```js
var input = 'FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=Doe&CUSTOMER_ID=284139';  // your API string

var field = 'LAST_NAME';  // could be any alphanumeric value

var newValue = 'Heisenberg';  // if you are a fan of Breaking Bad ;)

var regex = new RegExp(field+'=([^&]*)');  // combines 'field' with the regex

var output = input.replace(regex, field + '=' + newValue);  // does the actual replacement part

console.log(output);  // check your browser's console after running this
```

Learn more: [RegExp - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: I am sorry, I phrased my question incorrectly.  There can be an infinite number of fields and values.  I need to know how to find the field based on a variable name, not just searching for LAST_NAME or FIRST_NAME

Comment: @Straus818 Not sure if I understand you correctly, but `var field = 'LAST_NAME'` is probably what you mean? You can use this variable anywhere within the scope.

Comment: var field = document.getElementByID("selectDropDown).value

this is how I am getting the value of field.  It is dynamically chosen by a user

Comment: @Straus818 Please checkout my updated answer with the updated code. Yes, you can use `var field = document.getElementByID("selectDropDown).value;` along with my rest of the code.

Comment: This will work even though LAST_NAME is hardcoded into this?

Comment: @Straus818 Please check my updated code snippet. It now uses dynamic regex that is generated from a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
"FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=Doe&CUSTOMER_ID=284139".replace(/((^|&)LAST_NAME=)[^&]*/, "$1" + encodeURIComponent("Johnson"))
//"FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=Johnson&CUSTOMER_ID=284139"
```

---

Seems you need something like this:

```
var data = "FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=Doe&CUSTOMER_ID=284139";
var key = "FIRST_NAME";
data.replace(RegExp("((^|&)" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/\.\+\*\\\/\[\]\(\)\?/g, "\\$1") + "=)[^&]*"), "$1" + encodeURIComponent("Johnson"))
// "FIRST_NAME=Johnson&LAST_NAME=Doe&CUSTOMER_ID=284139"
```

Comment: Please see my edits.  I need to be able to use a variable name instead of LAST_NAME.  LAST_NAME was just an example,, but the field name could be anything.

Comment: Wow I have no idea what's going on in that regular expression.
Looks like I need to do some more studying.  I think I asked the question in a weird way that is over complicating things.  It looks like your version works, but I will have to change some values

Comment: @Straus818, I'm trying to escape special characters. But not sure that's all of them. Try searching for escaping, if you really need it ("but the field name could be _anything_") or just remove if you are sure it isn't nedded.

Comment: Oh I see.  No, the field name will usually only be alpha-numericals as far as I can tell.  Would this change the regex?  I really appreciate this!

Comment: @Straus818, you don't need to escape alphanumeric values. But not `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in node (javascript)

```
var a = "FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=Doe&CUSTOMER_ID=284139";
var field = "LAST_NAME";
var value = "Johnson";
var re = new RegExp("(" + field + "=)([A-Za-z]*)([&\s]*)");

a.replace(re, '$1'+ value + '$3');
    'FIRST_NAME=John&LAST_NAME=Johnson&CUSTOMER_ID=284139'
```

Comment: This looks great, but I'm getting the following errors:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Hmm - I did the above in node -no problems, I tried it in the web inspector in Safari -no problems. What javacsript environment are you using?

Comment: added some semicolons -the console allows you not to supply those, and I have been doing too much python of late.